# How to remove bool flag from linq query?

Tags: sql-server, database, linq

I have `Acts` table entity and Collection

```
public partial class Act
{
    public virtual ActCondition ActCondition { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Repair> Repair { get; set; }
}

public partial class Repair
{
    public virtual ICollection<RepairedDetails > RepairedDetails { get; set; }
}

public partial class RepairedDetails 
{
    public virtual Repair Repair { get; set; }
}
```

It have `Actcondition` table with primary key ActID 
Repair table linked with Act and `RepairedDetails` table linked with Repair table
How can I simplify and optimize this query

```
List<Act> acts = new List<Act>();
foreach (var item in db.Act.ToList())
{
    bool repflag = false;
    if (item.Repair != null &&
        item.ActCondition.ProcessedStorage == false &&
        item.ActCondition.ProcessedBookkeeping == false
        )
        foreach (var r_item in item.Repair)
            if (r_item.RepairedDetails != null)
                repflag = true;
    if (repflag == true) acts.Add(item);
}
```

How can I optimize that query?

Comment: Are you missing a `break;` in the inner foreach? If `item.Repair` has 1000 items and the first one sets the `repflag` to true, you are still looping over the other 999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (var item in db.Act.ToList())
{
    if (item.ActCondition.ProcessedStorage == false && item.ActCondition.ProcessedBookkeeping == false && item.ActCondition.Completed == false && item.ActCondition.ProductSent == false&& item.Repair.Any(nx => nx.RepairDetails.Count>0) ) 
    acts.Add(item);   
}
```

Comment: 'ICollection<Repair>' does not contain a definition for 'RepairedDetails'

Comment: List<Act> acts = new List<Act>();
            foreach (var item in db.Act.ToList())
            {
                if (item.ActCondition.ProcessedStorage == false &&
                        item.ActCondition.ProcessedBookkeeping == false &&
                        item.ActCondition.Completed == false &&
                        item.ActCondition.ProductSent == false&&
                        item.Repair.Any(nx => nx.RepairDetails.Count>0)
                    )
                    acts.Add(item);
            } works

Comment: @If OK. I have changed it - you are free to edit, too.

Comment: I have discovered that but does not .Count slowdown query?

Answer (score 2):

Do you use [Lazy loading](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx)?
It can have a bad influence on performance then it uses with `foreach`
Instead of db.Acts.ToList(), you should use db.Acts because.ToList() finalize the query and cast collection from IQueryable to IEnumerable.

You can use [Eager Loading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_eager_loading.htm) to manually join linked Entities.
I don't know what version of EF you use so that example for EF6.

```
var query = db.Act
    .Include(p => p.ActCondition)
    .Include(p => p.Repair)
    .ThenInclude(p => p.RepairedDetails).AsQueryable();

query = query.Where(item => item.Repair != null &&
        item.ActCondition.ProcessedStorage == false &&
        item.ActCondition.ProcessedBookkeeping == false && p.Repair.RepairedDetails.Any())

List<Act> acts = query.ToList();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! But 'IQueryable<Act>' does not contain a definition for 'ThenInclude' and no accessible extension method 'ThenInclude' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable<Act>' could be found . and where I ger "item" in your code?

Comment: 1. ThenInclude can be replaced by Include(p => p.Repair.RepairedDetails). It depends on the version EF.
2. Fixed.  act.Where(item => item.Repair ...

Comment: where do you define "act"? what is it?

Comment: Sorry too many mistakes without IDE :)

I divided into 2 expressions for a better understanding.

It should be:

query = query.Where(item => item.Repair != null &&
        item.ActCondition.ProcessedStorage == false &&
        item.ActCondition.ProcessedBookkeeping == false && p.Repair.RepairedDetails.Any())

Comment: Include(p => p.Repair.RepairedDetails) also not works. :(

Comment: Not works => error in runtime or during compilation?

Do you correctly set up your one-to-many relationship in Fluent API?
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx